# Custom profile for storage setting in Spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to set up Spinnaker on a private Kubernetes cluster. We are using a private S3 backed storage which needs a special param.

If I add that in ~/.hal/config,

> hal deploy apply

fails with unknown field error.

```
! ERROR Could not translate your halconfig: Unrecognized field
  "regionOverride" (class
  com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.config.model.v1.persistentStorage.S3PersistentStore),
  not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "rootFolder", "region", "endpoint",
  "accessKeyId", "bucket", "secretAccessKey", "connectionInfo",
  "pathStyleAccess"])
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain:
  com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.config.model.v1.node.Halconfig["deploymentConfigurations"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.config.model.v1.node.DeploymentConfiguration["persistentStorage"]->com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.config.model.v1.node.PersistentStorage["s3"]->com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.config.model.v1.persistentStorage.S3PersistentStore["regionOverride"])

- Failed to get deployment name.
```

But this fields work if add directly in the generated front50.yml file and restart the deployment.

```
persistentStorage:
    persistentStoreType: s3
    azs: {}
    gcs:
      rootFolder: front50
    redis: {}
    s3:
      bucket: test
      rootFolder: front50
      region: test
      endpoint: http://test.xyz.com
      accessKeyId: XXXXXXXXXXXX
      secretAccessKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      regionOverride: test
```

Currently, I add all these in a secret and redeploy the service in Kubernetes after hal deploy apply. Is there anyway to configure this in custom profile for front50 so that I don't need to redeploy front50.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  What do you mean by "needs a special param"? I see you added `test: ssfd`, is that why `hal deploy apply` is failing for you?  Later on you talk about adding "all these in a secret", what is "all these" you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, test:ssfd is what failing. So, I created a secret file whatever front50 instance needs and added this in the front50.yml and redeployed the instance with this yml.

Comment: Why are you adding `test: ssfd` to `~/.hal/config`? What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: The exact field is "regionOverride: test" which works with fron50? But, hal config throws error.

Answer (score 2):

Following configuration works perfectly with minio:

```
      persistentStorage:
        persistentStoreType: s3
        s3:
          bucket: spinnaker
          endpoint: http://minio.spinnaker.svc.cluster.local:9000
          rootFolder: spinnaker
          accessKeyId: KEY
          secretAccessKey: SECRET
```

Comment: Can we have this config in ~/.hal/default/profiles/fron50-local.yml?

Comment: I suppose yes, you can